# Showing feedback message using Visuaforce component and and Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

**Scenario:** we have an app installed in Salesforce for uploading files (the maximum limit is now 1gb). While uplaoding one file or multiple files the script gives the size and it needs to compare it to server. Now I have the size in a Visualforce component, but unable to send it to server side.

**Script:** in visualforce component

```
 <script>
     var fileUpload = jQuery('#fileupload'); 
     fileUpload.bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        jQuery.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
           var size= (file.size / (1024)).toFixed(2)+"KB";
             alert(size);
       });
     }) 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an hidden input field and bind that with the controller.

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!Value}" id="size"/>
```

Then use jquery to populate the value of the field.

```
$("#size").val = size;
```